# CNGroup.identifierについて

Tags: swift

CNGroup.identifier中は普通、
abcdefg1-abc2-abc3-abc4-abcdefg12345
となっているはずが、何がしらの条件が重なると、
abcdefg1-abc2-abc3-abc4-abcdefg12345:ABGroup:
と余計なものが付いてきます。

この「何がしらの条件」を特定しきれていませんがこれはバグでしょうか？
ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

試行回数が少ない＆ドキュメントには記載がないので憶測を含みますが、`:ABGroup`の suffix はローカルに作成されたグループのときに付与されるのかと思います。

## 説明

[Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts) の Containers and Groups の図を見ていただくと分かりやすいのですが、連絡帳から取得できる `CNContact` のデータソース（＝**アカウント**）は複数ありえます。

> A user may have contacts in their device’s local account and/or server accounts configured to sync contacts. Each account has at least one container of contacts. A contact can be in only one container.
>
> **私訳:** ユーザーはデバイスローカル、同期を設定したサーバーアカウントのいずれか、および複数の連絡帳を持つことができます。各アカウントは少なくとも一つの **コンテナ** を持ちます。連絡帳はひとつのコンテナの場合もあります。

ローカルデバイス、iCloud、Gmail、Facebook などなど端末に紐付けた様々なデータの集まりが連絡帳データです。

アカウントはひとつ以上の **`CNContainer`** と呼ばれる集まりを持っています。

> A group is a set of contacts within a container. Not all accounts support groups and some accounts support subgroups.
>
> **私訳:** **グループ** はコンテナ内の連絡帳のセットです。すべてのアカウントがグループをサポートしておらず、またいくつかのアカウントはサブグループをサポートしています。

**`CNGroup`** とは、この「 `CNContainer` 内部での連絡帳の集合」を表しています。

このため、

- グループの名前（`name`）
- グループの識別子（`identifier`）
- 保存先のコンテナ（`CNContainer`の`identifier`）

の３つの情報を持っているのですが、ローカルデータにグループを保存する場合には、データソースもコンテナもないので、`:ABGroup`の suffix で区別しているのだと思われます。

### ローカルへの保存

```
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
let group = CNMutableGroup()
group.name = "test group"
saveRequest.add(group, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
try! self.store.execute(saveRequest)
```

このように、`saveRequest.add(_,toContainerWithIdentifier:)` に `nil` を指定したケースではローカル保存となり、`:ABGroup` suffix が付与されます。

### サーバーアカウントへの保存

外部から連携されたグループ情報の読み込み時や、

```
let contact = /* グループに含めたい、外部から連携されているコンタクト */
let container = try self.store.containers(matching: CNContainer.predicateForContainerOfContact(withIdentifier: contact.identifier))
let containerIdentifier = container.identifier
```

ローカルデータ以外の `CNContact` から、`CNContainer` の `identifier` を取得し、`toContainerWithIdentifier:` に渡してグループを作成した場合には、`:ABGroup` suffix は付与されませんでした。